# How could I replace this CyclicBarrier with a lower level alternative?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm wondering how can I replace this CyclicBarrier with something else, like the usual `join`ing of all threads in an array. This is the snippet (try-catch blocks etc. ommited for clarity):

```
protected void execute(int nGens)
{
    CyclicBarrier thread_barrier = new CyclicBarrier(n_threads+1);
    ExecutorService thread_pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n_threads);
    for (int i=0; i<thread_array.length; i++) // all threads are in this array
        threadPool.execute(thread_array[i]);

    for (int i=0; i<total_generations; i++)
        threadBarrier.await();
    threadPool.shutdown();
    while(!threadPool.isTerminated()){}
}
```

and this is the code executed by the threads

```
public void run()
{
    for (int i=0; i<total_generations; i++)
    {
        next_generation(); // parallel computation (aka the 'task')
        thread_barrier.await();
    }
}
```

as you can see, all threads are launched on startup, then perform a certain task a number of times. Each time they finish a task, they wait until all other threads have finished their task, and then they perform it again. Are there any lower level ways to achieve this kind of synchronization?

Comment: But...why? This looks like an excellent use case for `CyclicBarrier`?

Comment: @Kayaman fair question - I want to check if a different method would be more time efficient

Comment: You should always prefer the more higher level concurrency primitives. While in some simple cases there may be differences in performance, it is minimal and far outweighed by other (actual) performance bottlenecks.

Comment: @Kayaman you're right - full disclosure, this question was prompted by a failed attempt at optimization via parallelization. Parallelizing this program has resulted in no improvements at all and I'm grasping at straws now. Here's the revelant CodeReview query https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185554/parallelization-not-speeding-up-program-possible-memory-bottleneck

Comment: Why not `threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.someUnit);`, rather than busy-waiting?

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code? If you're having performance issues, replacing `CyclicBarrier` is unlikely to help one bit.

Comment: You do understand that queued synchronizers are even faster than `synchronized`, which you might consider as "lower level," right? You're not going to get any faster than what `CyclicBarrier` already provides in this case, and even if you did find a "lower level" solution, it would not be worth your time in the end.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex Thanks man - your username makes me suspicious but I think you're right